# javascript function to handle activex in IE9

Tags: html

I'm creating a HTML page where I have a textbox and on button click if validation is true navigate to next page otherwise show alert.This functionality works fine in Firefox and Chrome but not in IE9.What happens is it just navigates to the next page no matter what the validation is.If i allow the activex to view the contents then it checks for the validation before navigation.This is a great security threat.How do I stop this navigation if it's validation is false.Any Suggestion?

Comment: You should always, *always* have server side validation *first*, then add client side validation *after* to aid user experience. Client side validation can easily be bypassed.